# PHP Customizing Module to show if DIV exists

Tags: php, popup, modal-dialog

I'm very new to PHP, so customizing ready-made scripts is no forte of mine quite yet.

I have an animated popup modal script, which currently triggers when a certain  is clicked. I'd also like to trigger this same script automatically when a particular div exists on the page.

The #mask, as you can see from the code, is a translucent layer of black over the page.

Here's the script that I need to adjust:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

    //select all the a tag with name equal to modal
    $('a[name=modal]').click(function(e) {
        //Cancel the link behavior
        e.preventDefault();
        //Get the A tag
        var id = $(this).attr('href');

        //Get the screen height and width
        var maskHeight = $(document).height();
        var maskWidth = $(window).width();

        //Set height and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
        $('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});

        //transition effect     
        $('#mask').fadeIn(1000);    
        $('#mask').fadeTo("slow",0.8);  

        //Get the window height and width
        var winH = $(window).height();
        var winW = $(window).width();

        //Set the popup window to center
        $(id).css('top',  winH/2-$(id).height()/2);
        $(id).css('left', winW/2-$(id).width()/2);

        //transition effect
        $(id).fadeIn(2000); 

    });

});
```

Currently it opens automatically when this link is clicked:

```
<a href="#" name="modal">
```

And I'm trying to get it to run automatically when this DIV exists on the page:

```
<div name="showintrovideo"></div>
```

Thanks so much guys, you're always such great help!

*- - Andrew*

**EDIT**

Here's the full code I'm working with:

HTML

```
<div id="boxes">
    <div id="qrcodemarketing" class="window">

        <!-- close button is defined as close class -->
        <div style="float:right;">
        <a href="#" class="close"><img src="images/close_window.png" width="22"height="22" alt="Close Window" /></a>
        </div>

        <iframe width="640" height="480" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/MYVIDEO" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe><br /><b>Pause the video before closing this window</b>

    </div>
    </div>




    <!-- Do not remove div#mask, because you'll need it to fill the whole screen --> 
    <div id="mask"></div>
```

CSS

```
#mask {
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  z-index:9000;
  background-color:#000;
  display:none;
}

#boxes .window {
  position:absolute;
  background:none;
  display:none;
  z-index:9999;
  padding:20px;
  color:#fff;
}
```

.js file

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

    //select all the a tag with name equal to modal
    $('a[name=modal]').click(function(e) {
        //Cancel the link behavior
        e.preventDefault();
        //Get the A tag
        var id = $(this).attr('href');

        //Get the screen height and width
        var maskHeight = $(document).height();
        var maskWidth = $(window).width();

        //Set height and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
        $('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});

        //transition effect     
        $('#mask').fadeIn(1000);    
        $('#mask').fadeTo("slow",0.8);  

        //Get the window height and width
        var winH = $(window).height();
        var winW = $(window).width();

        //Set the popup window to center
        $(id).css('top',  winH/2-$(id).height()/2);
        $(id).css('left', winW/2-$(id).width()/2);

        //transition effect
        $(id).fadeIn(2000); 

    });


    //if close button is clicked
    $('.window .close').click(function (e) {
        //Cancel the link behavior
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#mask, .window').hide();
    });     

    //if mask is clicked
    $('#mask').click(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $('.window').hide();
    });         

});
```

It it possible to just tweak the .js file so that it can also open automatically as well as by click?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're probably best using a session or cookie to determine whether to show the intro video. I'd also wrap your popup in a method you can call on a jQuery element. Something like:

```
$('a').myPopupMethod();
```

That way, you can also call it programmatically:

```
$.myPopupMethod();
```

In your HTML page, you can then use PHP to determine whether to show your popup or not:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $video_watched = $_SESSION['video_watched'];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
<?php if ($video_watched != true): ?>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.myPopupMethod();
        });
    </script>
<?php endif; ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, Martin!

Again, because I'm a rookie at this would you mind looking at my entire source code (which I added to the Question) to see how I can tweak it to work for both auto-opening and open-by-click?

I just have no idea how to integrate your solution. Please excuse my shortcomings.

Cheers!